# Is it safe to develop for iOS 6 exclusively?

Tags: ios, ios6

I've heard that a lot of users installed iOS 6 after Google released the Maps app for it, but have there been enough new users for it to be safe to develop for iOS 6?

Does it vary by demographic?

The app I'm making will be released in a week, and I don't know whether to make it for iOS 5+ or iOS6.

Comment: One thing to consider is that First-Gen-iPad cannot get iOS6.

Comment: The more versions you support, the more people will be able to use it.  Is there a specific IOS6 feature that you want to use?

Comment: Autolayout is one of the biggest, but also other things like the new phone ID for ads

Comment: @meisel Did you my answer help? If so you can tick!

Comment: Really? You're releasing in a week and you don't even know what versions of iOS you will support yet? To release in a week this means your app must be done and nearly finished with testing. If you suddenly decide to add support for iOS 5 then you have coding changes and you must complete several more rounds of testing on all versions of iOS. And what do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: @rmaddy Haha yeah, finally, time to insert my favorite quote. "You need to figure it the **** out" - Jimmy Tatro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, you will get a solid user base for iOS 6. Going back to iOS 5 would be great, but I have a friend who developed an app solely for iOS 6 and it has picked up a great user base and some traction.

Some things to consider is the first generation iPad is not compatible, and neither is any iPhone below 3GS.

The reasons to only develop for iOS 6 are there, like how you can use AutoLayout without it crashing on iOS 5.

I would estimate that there are over 200 million devices on iOS 6, not a small amount!

Personally, I think it is worth the efforts to build for iOS 5, the potential user base would definitely increase significantly and honestly, the efforts are not as much, you should focus more on building for iPhone 5.

However, iOS users are known to upgrade quickly and Apple is good at dispatching the OS for most phones, unlike Google/Android.

---

I would say it would extremely vary demographically. US will definitely hold majority of the updates and that is how it will always be. While places like India would not -- and India definitely has a growing mobile app user base.

Obviously if you are building for a iOS 6 only feature, this might get in the way, but its a sacrifice you have to make.

---

Coming to the Google Maps/Apple Maps fiasco, Google Maps for iOS made a difference, but not a major difference. It increased by around 30%, that is **good**, but not a killer difference.

It really applies to **your** app, its functionalities, its genre, its potential, its target market. Oh! What did I say? Target Market? Yes! Most important, if you are targeting education (schools) and apps for kids (family apps) then I would **most definitely** support iOS 5.

If you are developing a social networking, travel, gaming or productivity app (for example), I would be lenient, depends on the other above factors.

Hope this helped.